# Microsoft sculpt ergonomic keyboard waking up my screen

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, power-options

I have Microsoft sculpt ergonomic keyboard which wakes up my monitor as soon as display is turned off due to power setting. As a result, display is momentarily turned off and then turned on right away. Effectively this is keeping my display on forever.

Following link mentions the problem but there is no solution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/microsoft-sculpt-ergonomic-keyboard-waking-up-my/e0ac7dac-2395-4ab1-acd6-46c8e49c6f9d?auth=1

Is there any remedy for this? I have updated OS patches, device drivers and everything...

Comment: The workaround mentioned in the last post of the forum thread you linked should work. Also disable any wake-up from USB feature in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, I tried all those things. Also, changed BIOS settings. This is not getting fixed. I have another machine which was upgraded from Win-7 to Win-10, that machine doesn't have this problem. The brand new dell machine with Win-10 shows this issue. I have isolated the problem to MS keyboard dongle but there doesn't seem to be any fix.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, sorry, I was changing wrong setting. This indeed is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unchecking device manager->Human Interface Devices->Microsoft Hardware USB Keyboard->Power Management -> Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power, is indeed fixing this problem.

[image]

Comment: This did the trick for me too

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I'm playing a constant cat and mouse game with Microsoft when it comes to this keyboard and sleep…

Anyway, this worked for me on Windows 11:

1. Device Manager > Human Interface Devices.
2. There is no Microsoft Keyboard listed here, but there *is* "Microsoft Hardware USB Mouse" despite me not owning a Microsoft mouse. Hmm…
3. Power Management tab for the Microsoft Mouse has the "Allow this device to wake the computer" setting greyed out, but the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" box is checked. Uncheck this box and hit "OK."

After doing this, my system is able to sleep properly without the constant waking as soon as the display tries to sleep. I should also note that there are a bunch of different "HID Keyboard Device" entries under the Keyboards section. Turning off "Allow this device to wake the computer" for any of them does not fix the sleep issue, but does prevent me from pressing a key on the keyboard to wake up my system, so I recommend leaving these on.

Answer (score 1):

I unchecked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" for all of the Human Interface Devices that were installed when I plugged in the Sculpt dongle. For me, that solved the problem, and resolved some latency issues with the keyboard itself (missing key presses).

For the new issues this creates (not being able to "wake" the screen by clicking keys), I have a Logitech mouse which I "wake" the screen from...otherwise you can press keys on the keyboard that induce an on-screen function (ctrl-alt-del, windows key, etc.) as this also turns the display back on.

Answer (score 0):

I found that disabling the service "AMD External Events Utility" solved this problem for me (exact same symptoms, Windows 11)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the Microsoft Sculpt Keyboard connected to a Lenovo IdeaPad, which has an external monitor connected. The external monitor is the primary and no output goes to the laptop monitor. I have the same issue as the OP. I've tried all the recommendations in the previous answers and none of them worked for me. The best solution I have found is to turn on the screen saver before putting the monitor and laptop to sleep. By doing this, the keyboard is not able to interfere with the monitor going to sleep. Once the monitor goes to sleep the laptop will go to sleep as well.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1210486)

Comment: @Scott
 I have just tried this fix on Lenovo laptop a few days ago and it worked. I would suggest going through all Human Interface Devices and look for power management tab and uncheck "All the computer to turn off devices to save the power". It was worth at end.